# Java Database Not Returning Values

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to develop a simple program that asks for the user's name and phone number, adds it to a MySQL database, and returns the results. I have everything working up until the program is supposed to print the results of the database. Could somebody please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class ContactList {

static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://Devry.edupe.net:8300/CunninghamCustomer";

static final String USER = "3508";
static final String PASS = "******";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    Customer aCustomer = new Customer();

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (" + aCustomer.getName() + "," + aCustomer.getPhoneNumber() + ")";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        sql = "SELECT name, phone FROM CUSTOMER";
        ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs2.next()) {
            String name = rs2.getString("name");
            String phone = rs2.getString("phone");

            System.out.print("Name: " + name);
            System.out.print(", Phone Number: " + phone);
        }

        rs2.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch(SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        try {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Complete");
}

}

public class Customer {

String name = "Unknown";
String phoneNumber = "Unknown";
String message = "Contact Added!";

public Customer() {
    getInfo();
}

public void getInfo() {
name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Customer Name");
phoneNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Phone Number");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget the `values` in insert statement.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES(" + aCustomer.getName() + "," + aCustomer.getPhoneNumber() + ")";
```

Comment: Thanks a million, I've really been struggling with this!